# Write and read multiple objects to file

Tags: java, android, file, object

I am designing an handwriting application for android.

I would like to write information (`class LogInfo`) into a log file, every time the user presses the enter button.

After that, I would like to read the stored information.

*This is part of my class with a custom write method:*

```
public class LogInfo implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -5777674941129067422L;

public static List<Point[][]> strokes;
public static List<byte[]> codes;

// Only write and read methods shown

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream stream) throws IOException
{
    stream.defaultWriteObject();
    stream.writeInt(strokes.size());
    Point[][] pointsArray = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < strokes.size(); i++)
    {
        pointsArray = ((Point[][])strokes.get(i));
        stream.writeInt(pointsArray.length);
        for (int j = 0; j < pointsArray.length; j++)
        {
            stream.writeInt(pointsArray[j].length);
            for (int k = 0; k < pointsArray[j].length; k++)
            {
                stream.writeInt(pointsArray[j][k].x);
                stream.writeInt(pointsArray[j][k].y);
                //stream.writeObject(elementData[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    int size = codes.size();
    stream.writeInt(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        stream.write(codes.get(i));
    }
}
```

*This is the read method:*

```
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
    {
        stream.defaultReadObject();
        int strokesSize = stream.readInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < strokesSize; i++)
        {
            int arrayXSize = stream.readInt();
            Point[][] points = new Point[arrayXSize][];
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayXSize; j++)
            {
                int arrayYSize = stream.readInt();
                points[j] = new Point[arrayYSize];
                for (int k = 0; k < arrayYSize; k++)
                    points[j][k] = new Point(stream.readInt(), stream.readInt());
            }
            strokes.add(points);
        }

        int codesSize = stream.readInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < codesSize; i++)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[3];
            stream.read(buffer, 0, 3);
            codes.add(buffer);
        }
    }
```

It works well when I save only one object in the file. When I try to save more, reading is not working (it throws a `StreamCorruptedException`). **It reads only one object in the while loop!**

In the main class, I just use two simple methods:

```
// WRITE TO FILE
logInfo.writeLog();

// READ FROM FILE
ArrayList<LogInfo> logInfoArrayList = logInfo.readLog();
```

defined as:

```
public void writeLog()
{
    File file = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "data.log");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
        //fos = openFileOutput(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/data.log", Context.MODE_APPEND);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        os.writeObject(this);
        os.close(); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ArrayList<LogInfo> readLog()
{
    ArrayList<LogInfo> logInfoArray = new ArrayList<LogInfo>();

    try{
        File file = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "data.log");
        FileInputStream fis  = new FileInputStream(file);
        ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(fis);  

        LogInfo tempLogInfo = new LogInfo();
        while((tempLogInfo = (LogInfo)reader.readObject()) != null)
            logInfoArray.add(tempLogInfo);
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
     //TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return logInfoArray;
}
```

requested UPDATE:

```
//We use this class to not write a header in a file that already exist
class MyObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {

    public MyObjectOutputStream(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
        super(os);
      }

    @Override
    protected void writeStreamHeader() {}
}
```

Comment: Could you post the exception stack trace

Comment: 05-10 10:56:40.320: W/System.err(26121): java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Wrong format: ac
05-10 10:56:40.335: W/System.err(26121):  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.corruptStream(ObjectInputStream.java:701)
05-10 10:56:40.340: W/System.err(26121):  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:814)
05-10 10:56:40.345: W/System.err(26121):  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
05-10 10:56:40.350: W/System.err(26121):  at com.myapp.LogInfo.readLog(LogInfo.java:116)

Comment: It is incorrect to loop until null. readObject() doesn't return null at end of stream. It throws EOFException.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can't append to an existing file created with an `ObjectOutputStream`, at least not without effort. There is a trick somewhere about extending `ObjectOutputStream` and overriding the `writeStreamHeader()` method so as not to write the stream header the second time, but I'm not in favour of it. You should really rewrite the whole file, maybe as a List.
2. You don't need all this code. Just make `strokes` and `codes` non-static and non-transient, and get rid of the `readObject()` and `writeObject()` methods altogether.

Comment: Point class is not serializable. I can't resign from overriding readObject() and writeObject()

Comment: java.awt.Point is serializable. Are you using a different one?

Comment: I am using import android.graphics.Point. Also, when I make this field non-static, even with those methods I get an exception "Point non serializable". Why...?

Comment: Because it tries to serialize them automatically. I would make them non-static and transient.

Comment: Could you explain me more why I can't append to an existig file? I use "true" property in         fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);

Comment: I didn't say you can't append to an existing file. I said you can't append to an existing file *created with an `ObjectOutputStream`.* The reason is that `ObjectOutputStream` writes a header which `ObjectInputStream` isn't expecting to see in the middle of a file.

Comment: Could you recommend any other way to write multiple objects to a file? Andd to append new objects at the end of the file? I can't rewrite the whole file, it will be not effective if I will have something like 1000 objects and after creating new one I will have to write them all again...

Comment: after deleting "static" from the variable declaration, readObject() method see this object field as null, even that one line before calling readObject I initialized it and checked with debugger to make sure it is not null. Why it is like that?

Comment: Because you got a new object from readObject(), not the one you set the value in.

Answer (score 0):

@EJP is right.it cannot append to an existing file created with an ObjectOutputStream. You can do the following steps to fix it:
1. keep ObjectOutputStream object reference
2. after writeObject() having been called, do not call close()
3. provide a method to close ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: The problem has been already solved using custom ObjectOutputStream

Comment: How did you solve this? Would you mind post your custom ObjectOutputStream code?

Comment: You can find updated code in the question. You only have to override writeStreamHeader() method

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to save multiple objects in one file: you should first make an
object array (`Object [] objects`) and then put your objects one-by-one as an Object in this array and then write this array using `writeObject(objects)` method.
good luck.

Comment: There is a problem with this solution when you do not want to store the whole data in the RAM at the same time. It works while you can guarantee that the data fills in RAM.