# How to read different Object using ObjectInputStream in Java

Tags: java, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

Note: it's not a duplicate, because here we want to write not only Objects, but also a whole file, then read it back.

I have created a single `File` with 3 Objects using `ObjectOutputStream`,

1. `String`
2. `String`
3. `File` ( size is between [1 to 1.5]GB )

Below is my code whichever I have used to write the `File`

```
byte[] BUFFER = new byte[1024*32];
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("ThisIsTheFile.xyz");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("abcd.dat", true);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);      

String fileId = "BSN-1516-5287B-65893", fTitle = "Emberson Booklet";      

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){      
    if(i == 0){      
        oos.write(fileId.getBytes(), 0, fileId.length());
    }else if (i == 1){
        oos.write(fTitle.getBytes(), 0, fTitle.length());
    }else{
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while((bytesRead = is.read(BUFFER)) != -1){
            oos.write(BUFFER, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        is.close();
    }
}

fileId = fTitle = null;

oos.flush();
oos.close();
fos.flush();
fos.close();
fis.close();
```

Now my problem is:

1. I don't want to interrupt the `Java Heap Space` so read & write the large `File` streams using 32KB bytes buffer technique simultaneously.
2. Am I writing these three `Object` inside a single File separately & correctly?
3. Last but not least, **How should I retrieve these above said all 3 `Object` through `ObjectInputStream` from `"abcd.dat" File`?**

**Please help.**

Answer (score 2):

> I have create a file with 3 single objects

No. You have created a file with *no* objects and a whole lot of bytes, and no way of telling where one byte sequence stops and another starts. Use `writeObject(),` and read them with `readObject()`. The way you have it, there's no point in using `ObjectOutputStream` at all.

Note: appending to this file won't work. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473856/write-and-read-multiple-objects-to-file/16474129#16474129) for why.

Comment: I have followed you suggestion and now when I am casting the `String str1 =(String)objInputStream.readObject()` then only first string is getting assigned and for file `File file =(File)objInputStream.readObject()' and this is working. I tried `ArrayList<String> serializedObjectsList = (ArrayList<String>) oi.readObject();` but getting class cast exception. How to overcome this when we have more than one objects of same type and read all those objects seperately. If you could provide code sample, that would be great! :)